# Submit Button not firing in Razor Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am writing a web-app to submit incident forms. I am using the typical `@using (Html.BeginForm())` and then an input button at the bottom to submit the model.

My code for the view and controller is below.
My controller is under `~/Controllers/FormsController.cs`
My view is under `~/Views/Forms/Default.cshtml`

There is a lot of code that is all pretty much the same below, and I was put over my character limit, so I took a lot of it out.

Basically when I hit the "Submit Form" Button at the button, it doesn't go to the action method. Nothing happens. When I replaced it with:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Save", "Forms")'" />
```

It works, but I wasn't able to find a way to pass my model that way. It just calls the method but the model is null.

So my ultimate question is, why isn't my button working? I get these errors in Developer Tools in Chrome every time I hit the button. So looks like my jquery is messing something up.

1. **An invalid form control with name='MedicationGivenDescription' is not focusable.**
2. **An invalid form control with name='OtherTypeOfTreatmentDescription' is not focusable.**

**View:**

```
@model YMCA_Incident_Reports.Models.DefaultIncident
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Default Incident Form";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div>
<h1>YMCA of Burlington and Camden Counties</h1>
<p>Check appropriate Boxes</p>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Forms"))
{
<div class="table-bordered">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                ....
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Accident)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Accident)</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Incident)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Incident)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MountLaurel)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MountLaurel)</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Riverfront)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Riverfront)</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ChildCare)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ChildCare)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.PrimeTime)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PrimeTime)</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DayCamp)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DayCamp)</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CamdenExpansion)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CamdenExpansion)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   **More tables with other Html Helpers.**

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Form" />
</div>

}
```

**Controller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using YMCA_Incident_Reports.Models;

namespace YMCA_Incident_Reports.Controllers
{
public class FormsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Forms
    public ActionResult Default()
    {
        DefaultIncident model = new DefaultIncident();
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        model.TimeAndDateOfIncident = now;
        return View(model);
    }

    // Post: Forms

    public ActionResult Save(DefaultIncident model)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
}
```

**Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YMCA_Incident_Reports.Models
{
public class DefaultIncident
{
    public bool Accident { get; set; }
    public bool Incident { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Mt. Laurel")]
    public bool MountLaurel { get; set; }
    public bool Riverfront { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Child Care")]
    public bool ChildCare { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Prime Time")]
    public bool PrimeTime { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Day Camp")]
    public bool DayCamp { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Camden Expansion")]
    public bool CamdenExpansion { get; set; }
    public string SiteLocation { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your must provide a PhoneNumber")]
    [Display(Name = "Home Phone")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Phone number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string GuardiansName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeAndDateOfIncident { get; set; }
    public string IncidentDescription { get; set; }
    public string ResolutionDescription { get;  set;}

    //incident types
    public bool Argument { get; set; }
    public bool Language { get; set; }
    public bool Complaint { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Rule Enforcment")]
    public bool RuleEnforcment { get; set; }
    public bool Theft { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fight/Bullying")]
    public bool FightOrBullying { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Water Resuce")]
    public bool WaterRescue { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Innapropriate Behavior/Abuse")]
    public bool InnapropriateBehaviorOrAbuse { get; set; }

    //type of injury
    public bool Ache { get; set; }
    public bool Bite { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Bitten By Animal")]
    public bool BittenByAnimal { get; set; }
    public bool Bleeding { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Breathing Rapidly")]
    public bool BreathingRapidly { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Breathing Shallow")]
    public bool BreathingShallow { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Broken Bone Suspected")]
    public bool BrokenBoneSuspected { get; set; }

    public bool Bruise { get; set; }
    public bool Burn { get; set; }
    public bool Chocking { get; set; }
    public bool Cut { get; set; }
    public bool Drowning { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Near Drowning")]
    public bool NearDrowning { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Eye Injury")]
    public bool EyeInjury { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Foreign Object in Eye")]
    public bool ForeignObjectInEye { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Head Injury")]
    public bool HeadInjury { get; set; }
    public bool Itching { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nausea/Throw Up")]
    public bool NauseaOrThrowUp { get; set; }
    [Display(Name= "Nose Bleed")]
    public bool NoseBleed { get; set; }
    public bool Poisoning { get; set; }
    public bool Rash { get; set; }
    public bool Redness { get; set; }

    public bool Scrape { get; set; }
    public bool Scratch { get; set; }
    public bool Splinter { get; set; }
    public bool Sprain { get; set; }
    public bool Sting { get; set; }
    public bool Swelling { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Slip/Fall")]
    public bool SlipOrFall { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Other (Describe):")]
    public bool OtherTypeOfInjury { get; set; }
    public string OtherTypeOfInjuryDescription { get; set; }

    //place on body where it occured
    public bool LeftSide { get; set; }
    public bool RightSide { get; set; }

    public bool Abdomen { get; set; }
    public bool Arm { get; set; }
    public bool Ankle { get; set; }
    public bool Back { get; set; }
    public bool Buttocks { get; set; }
    public bool Cheek { get; set; }
    public bool Chest { get; set; }
    public bool Chin { get; set; }
    public bool Ear { get; set; }
    public bool Eye { get; set; }
    public bool Elbow { get; set; }
    public bool Finger { get; set; }
    public bool Foot { get; set; }
    public bool Forehead { get; set; }
    public bool Groin { get; set; }
    public bool Hand { get; set; }
    public bool Head { get; set; }
    public bool Hip { get; set; }
    public bool Knee { get; set; }
    public bool Leg { get; set; }
    public bool Lip { get; set; }
    public bool Mouth { get; set; }
    public bool Neck { get; set; }
    public bool Nose { get; set; }
    public bool Shoulder { get; set; }
    public bool Teeth { get; set; }
    public bool Thigh { get; set; }
    public bool Toe { get; set; }
    public bool Tongue { get; set; }
    public bool Wrist { get; set; }

    //Place where incident occured
    public bool Classroom { get; set; }
    public bool Playground { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fitness Center")]
    public bool FitnessCenter { get; set; }
    public bool Bathroom { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Weight Room")]
    public bool WeightRoom { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parking Lot")]
    public bool ParkingLot { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Adult Locker RM - M")]
    public bool AdultLockerRoomMen { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Adult Locker RM - W")]
    public bool AdultLockerRoomWomen { get; set; }

    public bool Babysitting { get; set; }
    public bool Kitchen { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Side Walk")]
    public bool SideWalk { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Family Locker RM - M")]
    public bool FamilyLockerRoomMen { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Family Locker RM - W")]
    public bool FamilyockerRoomWomen { get; set; }
    public bool Studio { get; set; }
    public bool Hallway { get; set; }
    public bool Bus { get; set; }
    public bool Car { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Pool Area")]
    public bool PoolArea { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Stretch Room")]
    public bool StretchRoom { get; set; }
    public bool Stairway { get; set; }
    public bool Field { get; set; }
    public bool Gym { get; set; }
    public bool Playzone { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Other (Describe):")]
    public bool OtherPlace { get; set; }
    public string OtherPlaceDescription { get; set; }

    //type of surface
    public bool Carpeting { get; set; }
    public bool Rubber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Tile Floor")]
    public bool TileFloor { get; set; }
    public bool Concrete { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Wood Floor")]
    public bool WoodFloor { get; set; }
    public bool Asphalt { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Wood Chips")]
    public bool WoodChips { get; set; }
    public bool Grass { get; set; }
    public bool Sand { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Other (Describe):")]
    public bool OtherTypeOfSurface { get; set; }
    public string OtherTypeOfSurfaceDescription { get; set; }


    //type of treatment given
    [Display(Name = "Cleaned with Soap and Water")]
    public bool CleanedWithSoapAndWater { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Antiseptic Applied")]
    public bool AntisepticApplied { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Bandage Applied")]
    public bool BandageApplied { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Ice Applied")]
    public bool IceApplied { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Rest Provided")]
    public bool RestProvided { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Removed Splinter")]
    public bool RemovedSplinter { get; set; }
    public bool Consoled { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Medication Given")]
    public bool MedicationGiven { get; set; }
    public string MedicationGivenDescription { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Other (Describe):")]
    public bool OtherTypeOfTreatment { get; set; }
    public string OtherTypeOfTreatmentDescription { get; set; }

    //where treatment was given
    [Display(Name = "At the center")]
    public bool TreatmentAtTheCenter { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Clinic/Doctor's Office")]
    public bool TreatmentAtClinicOrDoctorsOffice { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Emergency Room")]
    public bool TreatmentAtEmergencyRoom { get; set; }

    //follow-up actions
    [Display(Name="Parent/Emergency Contact Notified")]
    public bool ParentOrEmergencyContactNotified { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public string DateParentOrEmergencyContactNotified { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Time")]
    public string TimeParentOrEmergencyContactNotified { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Ambulance Called")]
    public bool AmbulanceCalled { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Poinson Control/Physician Called")]
    public bool PoisonControlOrPhysicianCalled { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Remained At Center")]
    public bool RemainedAtCenter { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Picked Up By Guardian/Drove Home")]
    public bool PickedUpByGuardianOrDroveHome { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Taken By Center Staff For Emergency Treatment")]
    public bool TakenByCenterStaffForEmergencyTreatment { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Name Of Emergency Care Facility:")]
    public string NameOfEmergencyCareFacility { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Condition Of Injury Upon Return To Center:")]
    public string ConditionOfInjuryUponReturnToCenter { get; set; }

    //witnesses
    [Display(Name="Staff Supervising Program/Area")]
    public string StaffSupervisingProgramOrArea { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Staff Who Performed First Aid")]
    public string StaffWhoPerformedFirstAid { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Person(s) who witnessed the accident")]
    public string WitnessesToAccident { get; set; }

    //signatures
    [Display(Name = "Staff Signature")]
    public string StaffSignature { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Staff Signature Date")]
    public string StaffSignedDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parent Signature")]
    public string ParentSignature { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parent Signature Date")]
    public string ParentSignatureDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Director Signature")]
    public string DirectorSignature { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Director Signature Date")]
    public string DirectorSignatureDate { get; set; }

}
}
```

Comment: Remove the `onclick=".."` in your submit button - that is making a redirect to a get method (not submitting your form). And you need to add `[HttpPost]` to the `Save()` method

Comment: I don't have an `onclick=".."` in my submit button. I also tried the `[HttpPost]` attribute as per the below suggestions but it did not work.

Comment: You do in the first snippet of code :) And you MUST add `[HttpPost]` and then the code WILL work unless you have other code you have not shown us that is preventing the submit

Comment: And as a side note, replace all your `DisplayNameFor()` with `LabelFor()` and do not use tables for layout

Comment: Sorry! That was an illustration to what I tried, but not currently in my code. I currently have `[HttpPost]` in my controller, but it still is not working. So something else must be limiting me. Also, I am a bit of a noob at this, so I don't understand how to format things without tables (I will get on researching that). Finally, why replace `DisplayNameFor()` with `LabelFor()`?

Comment: So it creates a label associated with the checkbox (or any other form controls you have in the view) - clicking on it the toggles the checked state (or sets focus to a textbox etc)

Comment: `DisplayNameFor()` doesn't do that? The only difference I see is `DisplayNameFor()` isn't bold, whereas `LabelFor()' bolds the display name. And I wanted it un-bolded so I switched. Both display the name fine, and don't seem to affect functionality for me?

Comment: No  - it just produces some text between your `<td>` tags and clicking on that text will do nothing. `LabelFor()` will produce a `<label>` element and associate it with the form control. And you can style it to look however you want - do not confuse appearance (css) with functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make the text-boxes for originally hidden fields not required. Didn't realize they were required (copy and paste issues). Once i took away the required attribute the button worked and passed the data!

Comment: …and because you don't have a @Html.ValidationSummary in your form, the errors were invisible but still prevented the form post?
…Which, if you didn't want to take away RequiredAttributes, you could fix by, instead of making it not-required, including the required fields as hidden inputs on the form?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple things going on. Based on your error, it looks like a validation library is trying to validate your form, and is encountering an error. You can disable the validation by using the `novalidate` attribute:

```
<form ... novalidate>
```

Also, your form is performing a POST action, but your action is expecting a GET action. Add the `HttpPost` attibute to your `Save` action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(DefaultIncident model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Without it MVC thinks `Save` it is a GET method by default. That is why your `location.href` works (when you change the href attribute, that triggers a GET action every time)

Comment: Meant to mention I tried this before too and also just now. Doesn't do the job. Maybe I need to add POST to the 'Html.BeginForm("Save", "Forms")' as well? But I thought it was POST by default. So I am not sure.

Comment: In that case, can you post the rendered html from your form? Also, what does your DefaultIncident model look like? Finally, what error message are you getting back from the server (use debugging tools)

Comment: I am not getting any errors back from the server. Seriously, none. I will also edit my post with the model.

Comment: You're getting something back from the server, though, right? What is coming back?

Comment: No, because nothing happens when I hit the button. Legit nothing, screen stays the same. Nothing new in any tab in debugging tools. Tried in IE, Edge, and Chrome.

Comment: In the debugging tools, is it even creating a POST request that you can see?

Comment: No it is not. The last things I see are GET requests for the css when the page initially loads.

Comment: Then that's the place to start. From what you're telling me, the form, for some reason, is not firing off the POST action. Is the onclick event in your submit button still assigned a function? That could be hindering the default behavior of the button.

Comment: If you post the rendered html of your form, that could help too.

Comment: So I suck, I have a different problem where my check boxes don't show up in chrome. So I never really bothered using it and that is the only place errors show up. I got two errors back from the server when I click the button. They are listed in the post.

Comment: Based on your error, it looks like there is some jquery functionality somewhere that is interfering with the POST action of the form. Are you using any form validation libraries?

Comment: Check my lastest answer. I fixed it. I made two hidden text boxes not required, didn't realize I set them to required.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend specifying the form type explicitly. So the view's form declaration would look something like this:

```
Html.BeginForm("Save", "Forms", FormMethod.Post)
```

Then your controller would look something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(DefaultIncident model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Alternatively, you can change both verbs to GET if that is what you are looking to accomplish instead.

Comment: I tried this, no such luck. As per my comment on the other suggestion, I thought this may have been the case but it defaults to POST and even when explicitly saying that, it still doesn't do the trick. I also need post, because I need to get the updated values to the model from the form.